# Type contract is not implicitly convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity, addresses

what is the wrong with this function 
i can't get the address of LenderRegistration contract

```
mapping (address=>address) lendersToContracts;    
function lenderRegister(uint256 _rentedStorage) public isNewLender returns (bool) {
    lendersToContracts[msg.sender] = new LenderRegistration(Admin, _rentedStorage, Token, msg.sender);
    lenderIndex++;
    return true;
}
```

the error after compiling

```
typeError: Type contract LenderRegistration is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
        lendersToContracts[msg.sender] = new  LenderRegistration(Admin, _rentedStorage , Token ,msg.sender);
```

Comment: isNewLender   is a modifier , 
and LenderRegistration is another contract that i imported with 4 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "explicit conversions": https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#address

```
lendersToContracts[msg.sender] = address(new LenderRegistration(...));
```